# How can i preserve the current overlay position while rotate the overlay

Tags: ffmpeg

this is my first question here and i hope it be good start to me

i have the following command to overlay image above image

```
   String command = '-y -i $backgroundImage1 -i $overlayImage1 -filter_complex '
                '"[1]scale=500:500,rotate=1:c=none:ow=rotw(1):oh=roth(1)[i1];'
                '[0][i1]overlay=600:600" $outPutPath';
```

the result work fine but the overlay position seems to be not exactly as provided , so i decide to remove `:ow=rotw(1):oh=roth(1)` and it preserved the current position exactly as provided but the problem it auto cropped some parts

so i want like to preserve the current overlay and avoiding any auto parts cropped , How could i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Keep the `ow` and `oh` in rotate and change overlay to `overlay=600-w/2:600-h/2` if you want the centre of the overlay to remain at `(600,600)`

Comment: thanks you for response , i just tested it but it became worst , overlay positions completely changed it position and not the same

Comment: *overlay positions completely changed it position* --> what does this mean?

Comment: simply you can imagine the commend is without rotate , so the 600:600 will be difference before-after adding rotate . even with edit overlay to 600-w/2:600-h/2 . on other word the accepted result like exactly occurs when i remove :ow=rotw(1):oh=roth(1)  . so i thought with adding 600-w/2:600-h/2 the result will be the same as when i remove :ow=rotw(1):oh=roth(1) but is not . in general you can imagine the accepted result is like that position without  :ow=rotw(1):oh=roth(1)

Comment: center is 600+500/2=850, so `overlay=850-w/2...`